# New Selenium User

Tags: silverlight, testing, selenium, automation, selenium-ide

I m new to Selenium automation testing. 
I installed Selenium IDE and i need to install something to test Silverlight web applications. Can anyone guide me to get it right? 
As for the Selenium RC, how can i install it and use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to read http://learnwpf.com/post/2012/06/27/Silverlight-Automated-UI-Testing-With-Selenium.aspx and try https://code.google.com/p/silverlight-selenium/.

Comment: Also i came across this link it might help: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html

Answer (score 0):

To configure selenium in your system U need.
1.Selenium RC (http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar)
2.selenium java client driver(http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-java-2.25.0.zip)
3.TestNG.jar(find the latest version..I think 5.5)(if you are using testNG framework)
First of all Go to Eclipse market place and have TstNG framework installed.
then add java client driver and testNG.jar to refrenced libraries to ur project.
U can run Selenium rc from cmd prompt or Eclipse. create a testNG file for exectuion of tests and start execution.